# Strange Apache behavior parsers anything.php.anything

Tags: php

I cleared a server with some shells uploaded with the help of joomla 1.5. I managed to clear the shells but on closer inspection the Apache runs every php file script like: anything.php.anything with the condition that .php exists in filename.

The httpd conf files are intact and without *AddType application* and there is no htaccess file.

Any idea from where to change this behavior?

System: `Linux  2.6.18-194.32.1.el5 #1 SMP Wed Jan 5 17:52:25 EST 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Have you checked about [mod_mime](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/90969/32746)?

Comment: mod_mime is enabled and looks fine. Any config files to check for?

Comment: @calculataur: If your issue is solved, could you put your solution in an answer and mark it as a good answer instead of updating the question? It would be interesting also if you could tell the value **before** modification so your post could serve as a reference telling the initial configuration, the issue caused by it and the corresponding solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RESOLVED by modifying php handler:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler php5-script
</FilesMatch>
```